# How to add URL to an image in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Using object.on('selected', function() {}), I can get the image object that is clicked. My intent is to redirect to an URL by clicking it. How can I add an URL to an image, or more general, to an object in Fabric.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply navigate to the target page in the `selected` event handler:

```
object.on('selected', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
})
```

Comment: I want to save the URL in the object.

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by save? You can just do `object.associatedUrl = 'http://www.example.com/'` and then in the selected handler do `window.location.href = this.associatedUrl;` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Do you want to save the canvas on database?

Comment: This works well, thank you! Two things that helped me implement: (1) the object has to be selectable, so if you have `journalName.selectable = false` then it won't work, obviously, and (2) it has to go before you `canvas.add(object)`.